# I don't understand using get-content on a csv

Tags: powershell

How come when I do `(Get-Content $CSV1)[2]` in the Power-shell console on any .csv file I get the field but when I do it in the ISE I get errors like this.

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv"
(Get-Content $CSV1)[2]
```

usersF.csv contents

```
GivenName
Ylnum
Dexcd
Igbos
Rzjlr
```

Errors

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\ovie_lab7_merged.ps1:5 char:1
+ (Get-Content $CSV1)[2]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

I've tried the solution @TheIncorrigible1 gave me and it worked, but now I'd like to export that data to a .csv and instead of the string I got the string length in the .csv file how can I fix this?

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv"
$test = $CSV1.GivenName[4]

$test | Export-Csv "C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\test.csv"

#TYPE System.String
Length
5
```

Comment: What is  `$CSV1`? Is it a relative path? The working directory in both shells could be different. That file contains no data possibly? if `$CSV1` was null your error should be different. You need to debug this more yourself.

Comment: I suspect you're using dynamic pathing and the current location is different in ISE.

Comment: The path $CSV1 is to the .csv and the fields are bellow it. sorry quick edit*

Comment: The code order you have there is confusing. Is that how you are running it? `Get-Content` with the error _then_ you use `Import-CSV`? You have the same variable name for different variable types so it is also confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem you're running into is a simple type understanding problem.

`Import-Csv` takes the Path you provide to it and imports that into a `PSCustomObject`.  You're trying to `Get-Content -Path [PSCustomObject]`, but that is not a supported type for the `-Path` argument (if you read the help topic, it expects a `[String[]]`).

If you want that first line, you should do something like:

```
$Path = 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv'
@(Get-Content -Path $Path)[1] #Arrays are zero-indexed
```

Alternatively,

```
$Csv = Import-Csv -Path $Path
$Csv.GivenName[0]
```

---

To address your edit, you aren't calling `Export-Csv` properly.  It expects a `PSCustomObject`, but you're passing it a single string.  I'd suggest using `Out-File` instead.

```
$CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\usersF.csv
$test = $CSV1.GivenName[4]

$test |
    OutFile -FilePath C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\lab8\test.csv
```

Comment: @Ovie If my answer solved your problem, please click the checkmark next to it to represent your question is answered.

Comment: there is still one problem when exporting the data to a .csv file is there anyway you can help me understand I posted the problem at the bottom of my original post